# can REST webservice return an exception?

Tags: angular, rest

I am calling a REST webservices from my angular application to get a person's address, if its available then I receive the json response something like below, but in case of no address(no data) then the rest webservices(endpoint) returning 404 exception rather than a error response JSON, so I am forced to handle the no data scenario as an error inside my subscribe. is that correct a rest web services can return an exception for no data scenario ?

```
{
  "@type": "PostalAddress",
  "addressLocality": "Colorado Springs",
  "addressRegion": "CO",
  "postalCode": "80840",
  "streetAddress": "100 Main Street"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes. it is absolutely correct and expected

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct for a REST web service to return an error (exception).

This is indicated by the return code of the HTTP response.

If no data is not an exception for this service, it might not return an error, but this is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

> is that correct a rest web services can return an exception for no data scenario ?

Maybe.

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. -- [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5)

That language applies when the server is reporting either a client error (4xx) or a server error (5xx).

The tricky part is that whether or not "no data" is an error depends in part on the nature of the resource itself.

For example, if GET a representation of a search result from google, and that search has no matches, what you normally see is a `200 OK` status, and a representation of the search result that says something like "no results found".

Similarly, if you ask a web server for a copy of a document, and the document is empty (zero bytes long), then you'll normally get a 200 OK message with an empty payload.

HTTP tells us how to describe payloads that are representations of the requested resources, and it tells us how to describe payloads that are representations of an error situation, but it doesn't actually tell you what response to send.

As the consumer of an API, you are expected to look at the status code, and often also the content-type header on the HTTP response, to understand how to correctly interpret the payload.